# Pulling dynamic CDATA from a webpage using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to download the entire HTML from every one of these [54897 pages](https://www.parlament.ch/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista).  Selenium, however, doesn't reload the page, when it clicks on next page, at least only superficially. After running the code, I realised that all of the 54897 files were identical. It just kept downloading the first file. Can anybody see a solution to this problem? Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import progressbar
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://www.parlament.ch/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista'
driver.get(url)

bar = progressbar.ProgressBar()

for elem, i in zip(range(0,5489), bar(range(5489))):
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    html = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html5lib')

    file = open('myfolder/' + str(elem) + ".txt", "w")
    file.write(str(html))
    file.close()

    time.sleep(1.5)
    driver.find_element_by_id('PageLinkNext').click()

    time.sleep(0.02)
```

Answer (score 0):

As often happens, you need to get the DOMs for pages you load.

Here I load the first page, click for the next one, obtain its DOM on the basis of the `id` of the `body` element. I ask for the `innerHTML` for this element so that (a) I can parse it using BeautifulSoup to demonstrate that the content differs from the first page, and (b) it could be saved to a file as one of your 50,000-odd documents.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get('https://www.parlament.ch/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista')
>>> driver.find_element_by_id('PageLinkNext').click()
>>> DOM = driver.execute_script('return document.getElementById("ng-app").innerHTML;')
>>> page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(DOM, 'lxml')
>>> page.find_all('h4', {'class', "ms-srch-item-area"})
[<h4 class="ms-srch-item-area"> <a href="/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista/geschaeft?AffairId=20173611">Interpellation - Herzog Verena</a> </h4>, <h4 class="ms-srch-item-area"> <a href="/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista/geschaeft?AffairId=20173610">Interpellation - Tornare Manuel</a> </h4>, <h4 class="ms-srch-item-area"> <a href="/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista/geschaeft?AffairId=20173609">Postulat - Gmür Alois</a> </h4>, <h4 class="ms-srch-item-area"> <a href="/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista/geschaeft?AffairId=20173608">Interpellation - Reynard Mathias</a> </h4>, <h4 class="ms-srch-item-area"> <a href="/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista/geschaeft?AffairId=20173607">Motion - FDP-Liberale Fraktion</a> </h4>, <h4 class="ms-srch-item-area"> <a href="/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista/geschaeft?AffairId=20173606">Interpellation - Bourgeois Jacques</a> </h4>, <h4 class="ms-srch-item-area"> <a href="/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista/geschaeft?AffairId=20173605">Motion - Gmür-Schönenberger Andrea</a> </h4>, <h4 class="ms-srch-item-area"> <a href="/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista/geschaeft?AffairId=20173604">Motion - Fraktion BD</a> </h4>, <h4 class="ms-srch-item-area"> <a href="/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista/geschaeft?AffairId=20173603">Postulat - Dettling Marcel</a> </h4>, <h4 class="ms-srch-item-area"> <a href="/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista/geschaeft?AffairId=20173602">Postulat - Mazzone Lisa</a> </h4>]
>>> driver.quit()
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get('https://www.parlament.ch/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista')
>>> driver.find_element_by_id('PageLinkNext').click()
>>> DOM = driver.execute_script('return document.getElementById("ng-app").innerHTML;')
>>> import bs4
>>> page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(DOM, 'lxml')
>>> page.find_all('h4', {'class', "ms-srch-item-area"})
[<h4 class="ms-srch-item-area"> <a href="/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista/geschaeft?AffairId=20173611">Interpellation - Herzog Verena</a> </h4>, <h4 class="ms-srch-item-area"> <a href="/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista/geschaeft?AffairId=20173610">Interpellation - Tornare Manuel</a> </h4>, <h4 class="ms-srch-item-area"> <a href="/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista/geschaeft?AffairId=20173609">Postulat - Gmür Alois</a> </h4>, <h4 class="ms-srch-item-area"> <a href="/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista/geschaeft?AffairId=20173608">Interpellation - Reynard Mathias</a> </h4>, <h4 class="ms-srch-item-area"> <a href="/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista/geschaeft?AffairId=20173607">Motion - FDP-Liberale Fraktion</a> </h4>, <h4 class="ms-srch-item-area"> <a href="/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista/geschaeft?AffairId=20173606">Interpellation - Bourgeois Jacques</a> </h4>, <h4 class="ms-srch-item-area"> <a href="/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista/geschaeft?AffairId=20173605">Motion - Gmür-Schönenberger Andrea</a> </h4>, <h4 class="ms-srch-item-area"> <a href="/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista/geschaeft?AffairId=20173604">Motion - Fraktion BD</a> </h4>, <h4 class="ms-srch-item-area"> <a href="/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista/geschaeft?AffairId=20173603">Postulat - Dettling Marcel</a> </h4>, <h4 class="ms-srch-item-area"> <a href="/de/ratsbetrieb/suche-curia-vista/geschaeft?AffairId=20173602">Postulat - Mazzone Lisa</a> </h4>]
```

If this works for you, please mark it 'accepted' so that others will find it.